# Remove Duplicates in SSRS Subreport

Tags: reporting-services, duplicates, lines

I have an SSRS report the links a line item subreport to my main report by an order number. When a customer orders 2 line items, 2 order numbers come in with contact info, etc. In the SSRS report, the order number shows up twice and the multiple line items fall below. What I would like is the 1 order number with the line items following.

As I have it now it looks like:

```
Order#  Contact  User
1234    J. Smith JS1

LineItem  Qty  Order Date
1         3    05/15/2015
2         2    05/15/2015

Order#  Contact  User
1234    J. Smith JS1

LineItem  Qty  Order Date
1         3    05/15/2015
2         2    05/15/2015
```

I tried =Fields!LineItem.Value =PREVIOUS(Fields!LineItem.Value) but because the dup isn't directly previous that didn't work.

But I'd like to have just one single result. Any help would be great.

Comment: Rather than an expression, isn't this a row grouping situation?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your design screen should be the Row Groups window. Many times, you will already have a group created. If you right click on it and click the properties it should look something like the image below:
[image: possibly how you want to group your rows]

Thanks.